# Why am I getting a HTTP-400 Bad Request error with webmatrix cshtml?

Tags: razor, webmatrix, http-status-code-400

Why if I submit an URL like:

`localhost:38245/TeamWork/Group/1/LONG-COMMENT-POSTED-BY-USER` ,

I get an error that says "Bad Request - invalid URL HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid." ?

Answer (score 1):

The default maximum length of a URL is 4096 in IIS. You may well be breaching that with the comment posted by the user. Generally, the best way to transfer that kind of data is by POST rather than in a URL. You can either trim the comment to a more suitable size of increase the maxUrl value in the requestLimits section of your IIS config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, HTTP 400 error is intended for cases when the client has made an error. As you've noticed yourself it's a bad request error. So that means possibly due to bad syntax the request can not be carried out. As Mike Brind mentions, you're most probably exceeding the maximum length of the URL (the default value anyway)

Secondly, why are you trying to "submit" a long post by URL? Use the POST method instead. A way to do this is by using Jquery's Post method to do this. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Or simply by calling the form's submit method through OnClick method or however the user is submitting the form.

POST is perfect for transmitting large amounts of data. So submitting data from the client side, the easiest way by far is to use POST to archieve this.

Comment: My problem is that I am usin a XMLHttp requets to get the value of a (for example) textarea (where the user writes the comment) and it send it in a form of a link (like the one that I showed) to a cshtml file that inserts the "LONG-COMMENT-POSTED-BY-USER" into the databse. So anytime I write a long post, it shows me that 400 error. Do I still have to use "post"?

Answer (score 0):

As you have yourself stated in the Question code part,

```
localhost:38245/TeamWork/Group/1/LONG-COMMENT-POSTED-BY-USER
```

the Long comment by user, must be inside the limits that are in the `web.config` file of your website.

Secondly, no Server would allow a very Long Url thinking that the user might be trying to post a malware. Also, using short URLs is good for Data transfer as they consume less data.

From the limits on Requests one would easily come to understand that the URL must be less than 4096bytes, only 4KB. So do you think, all that URL would be 4KB?

As Mike has suggested to use POST request to send the long data, I would also suggest you to use HttpPost requests to send this type of long data. This way, Browser would encrypt the data and sending it as an attachment to the request.